# Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(withRedux(MyApp))"

Tags: reactjs, redux, firebase-authentication, next.js

I am trying to do authentication in Nextjs using firebase and redux but I run into this error when I use `connect` from `react-redux`.

[image: Unhandled Runtime Error]

**Note**: I'm not a pro so do forgive me if my code seems bad.

```
import "../styles/global.scss";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import App from "next/app";
import { Provider, connect } from "react-redux";
import withRedux from "next-redux-wrapper";
import { auth, createUserProfileDocument } from "../firebase/firebase.utils";
import store from "../redux/store";
import { setCurrentUser } from "../redux/user/user.actions";

class MyApp extends App {
  static async getInitialProps({ Component, ctx }) {
    const pageProps = Component.getInitialProps
      ? await Component.getInitialProps(ctx)
      : {};

    //Anything returned here can be access by the client
    return { pageProps: pageProps };
  }

  unsubscribeFromAuth = null;

  componentDidMount() {
    const { setCurrentUser } = this.props;

    this.unsubscribeFromAuth = auth.onAuthStateChanged(async (userAuth) => {
      if (userAuth) {
        const userRef = await createUserProfileDocument(userAuth);
        userRef.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
          setCurrentUser({
            id: snapshot.id,
            ...snapshot.data(),
          });
        });
      } else {
        setCurrentUser(userAuth);
      }
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribeFromAuth();
  }

  render() {
    //Information that was returned  from 'getInitialProps' are stored in the props i.e. pageProps
    const { Component, pageProps, store } = this.props;

    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

//makeStore function that returns a new store for every request
const makeStore = () => store;

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  setCurrentUser: (user) => dispatch(setCurrentUser(user)),
});

const wrappedApp = withRedux(makeStore)(MyApp);

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(wrappedApp);
```

I have a sandbox link [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-allen-bvkyp?file=/firebase/firebase.utils.js).
Please help

Comment: Try adding the <Provider> in the parent component. Use explicit imported store variable, not from props.

Comment: I tried to use explictly imported store variable. got same error. How do I add <provider> in parent component? sorry about my lack of knowledge (I'm still new to this).

Comment: When you render the MyApp component it should be wrapped in provider like this:
<Provider store={store}><MyApp/></Provider>
Here is documentation: https://react-redux.js.org/api/provider

Comment: I tried. Same error again. Please check my codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-allen-bvkyp?file=/pages/index.js

Comment: When you render it in parent component, not in render function of MyApp.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you

Comment: Please just read the documentation, as the answer is there: https://react-redux.js.org/api/provider